# Sugarcrm Editing in-line date field automatically date format is changing as yyyy-mm-dd .i need as mm/dd/yyyy

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

When Editing dates in in-line edit, it returns in the yyyy-mm-dd. i need it to display in mm/dd/yyyy format .How can i achive this functionality .   Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I assume as you've not provided any code that you are asking about setting it through the GUI.

I've flagged this as not related to programming, as you can find this by clicking the image at the top right, and going to Profile.

Click Edit, Advanced tab, and locale settings.

From here, you can set the date format for your user.

[image: Profile Locale]

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date('2010-10-11T00:00:00+05:30');

console.log((date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear());
```